# Run a . exe file genarated using pyinstaller outside my venv is not working

Tags: python, package, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I converted a xxxx.py to a yyyy.exe using pyinstaller, after a lot of modifications, and googling I managed to make the yyyy.exe work inside my venv, but when I switched outside venv(base), the yyyy.exe did not work, it seems that when yyyy.exe is executed,it still looking to import libraries from site packages in my local machine insted of looking inside dist folder where all needed libararies are installed. I do care about this  issue since I m going to share only my file.exe with collegues not (file.exe and the venv) And it should work for them.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: please provide logs and errors. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: Error : no mudule named '_backports'. This module is available in my dist folder, but as explained before since the yyyy.exe is importing libraries from the base which in turn does not have this module, normally the yyyy. exe should look for this module inside dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think your program has a dependency problem.
You have to install(build dependency tree) the .exe file before running.
You have to build an installer for it.

**See:**
[Inno setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
for a good package creator.

here is a good tutorial:[in youtube](https://youtu.be/rxLdBDJjER4)

Note, there are many good options for this work, feel free to check out them.

Comment: Do u know any installer for ubuntu

Comment: .exe files are only for windows, how did you manage to run your exe inside a Debien os, while even inside a venv?

Comment: for ubuntu or kali like os see-   
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401381/debianzing-a-python-program-to-get-a-deb